# Or logic sequel

Tags: sql

Here is a part of the code I am copying here. The logic where I am stuck is I want to count the hits for all channels other than sky sports and (other tv with genre description sports)
I dont think my or logic works here.

```
count(case when CHANNEL_NAME NOT IN('Sky Sports 3'
,'Sky Sports 1'
,'Sky Sports 2'
,'Sky Sports 4'
,'Sky Sports F1'
,'Sky Sports Ashes'
,'Sky Sports Interactive Lo 7'
,'Sky Sports Interactive Lo 1'
,'Sky Sports Ineractive Hi 5'
,'Sky Sports Ineractive Hi 1'
,'Sky Sports Ineractive Hi 4'
,'Sky Sports Interactive Lo 9'
) or (channel_name <> 'Other TV' and genre_description <> 'Sports') then 1 end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `or` is inaccurate here. If the name is `"Other TV"`, for instance, it will match the first criteria (the name is not `"sky sports something"`) and will be included. You should use `and` because you want your channels to meet *all* criteria.

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(case when CHANNEL_NAME LIKE 'Sky Sports%'
                OR (channel_name = 'Other TV' AND genre_description = 'Sports')
           then 0 
           else 1
      end)
```

Comment: I think you should insert brackets around conditions `channel_name <> 'Other TV' and genre_description <> 'Sports'`

Comment: @Nadeem_MK: Actually they are not needed since `and` binds stronger than `or`. But for readability - yes.

Comment: @juergend in count function if we use both 0 and 1 then it counts all ! it has got to be either 0 end or 1 end for it to count only what we filtered for

Comment: @you can also use `sum`